# How to mount PCIe SSD from MacBook Air in another computer

Tags: ssd

I got this SSD out of an Apple laptop that's broken from liquid damage.

What is this connection called and how do I mount this storage device to retrieve data from it? It looks like PCIe. Does Apple sell a part to mount this via USB adapter or something?

[image]

Comment: What MacBook Air model and year is this from?

Comment: MacBook Air "Core i5" 1.4 13" (Early 2014), Model A1466 (EMC 2632)

Comment: I have the same issue. I have the same SSD from a 2014 MacBook Air (A1466) and it is marked as a "Sandisk SD6PQ4M" 256G drive. The machine is not booting and I'd like to try to recover this by using it during OS X install on another MacBook, or at least mount it as an external drive.

I don't own a PC, so none of the pre-2018 links lead to anything I can use. Has anyone found a solution that works in OS X?

Comment: @FranK. for OSX, boot to Recovery (`R+Command`), then use diskutil in terminal to access the disk. The disk will not show in Disk Utility, you have to use terminal. Watch video for demo: https://youtu.be/47--98JReaU?t=45

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The physical interface(s) or form factor(s) are Apple proprietary. The different SSDs have 6+12/12+16/8+18/7+17 pins. The electrical/logical interface is PCIe 2.0 2x or 4x (everymac.com also mentions SATA for some older MacBook Airs).

Several adapters for different MacBook (Air) SSDs are available [here](http://www.pc-adapter.net/categories/0/0/57/1.html).

Example: [MacBook Air Mid 2013 SSD to PCI-e 1X](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003188136566.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.80466d9blGeb5d&algo_pvid=6b82f063-47b9-4465-a2a4-0b4590545e38&algo_exp_id=6b82f063-47b9-4465-a2a4-0b4590545e38-6&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000024569241587%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21MYR%21%2135.44%21%21%21%21%21%4021365ec216537094368431969e85ac%2112000024569241587%21sea)
[image]

I haven't been able to find an adapter for the MacBook Air Early 2015 SSD there. The latest MacBook Air uses a proprietary PCIe 2.0 4x instead of a proprietary PCIe 2.0 2x interface like older MacBook Airs.

Comment: Is there anything china can't do with apple stuff : )

Answer (score 5):

the "SNANSHI 2013-2014 Year MacBook Air A1465 A1466 Pro A1502 A1398 MD712 SSD PCI-e 4X Adapter" for $13.99 worked perfectly for me, and I can use the drive as a primary boot drive for my PC.  The card is recognized as a SATA device in my BIOS, and it works flawlessly.  Good Luck

Comment: Looks like a good option: https://www.amazon.com/SNANSHI-2013-2014-MacBook-A1465-Adapter/dp/B012Y8F6A4

Answer (score 4):

There is an adapter that would allow you to mount this as an external drive:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/pin-28pin-Adapter-2013-2014-Macbook/dp/B014FTKOWA

It is on the expensive side but its USB 3.0 and PnP.

Comment: That is expensive but it made me dig around some more. I've found one on the US store, also expensive: https://smile.amazon.com/QNINE-Enclosure-MacBook-External-Adapter/dp/B076KDPZMM/ref=sr_1_3

Answer (score 0):

Use adapter below, with max speed 600MB/s

Adapter Name :  **Xiwai PCI Express Convert Card PCI-E 1X to 12+16 Pin 2013-2017**

[AliExpress Link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003188136566.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.80466d9blGeb5d&algo_pvid=6b82f063-47b9-4465-a2a4-0b4590545e38&algo_exp_id=6b82f063-47b9-4465-a2a4-0b4590545e38-6&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000024569241587%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21MYR%21%2135.44%21%21%21%21%21%4021365ec216537094368431969e85ac%2112000024569241587%21sea)

[image]